# Debian aptitude: determine which repository a package is coming from?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, aptitude

In Aptitude, how can I tell where a package is coming from? I've set up my apt `sources.list` and `preferences` files for pinning, but I just want to make sure I'm not unknowingly upgrading to packages from backports or unstable.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/106794/how-to-tell-from-what-ubuntu-or-debian-repository-a-package-comes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apt-cache policy $packagename` will tell you what you want to know. For example:

```
$ apt-cache policy gnucash
gnucash:
  Installed: 1:2.4.2-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1:2.4.2-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1:2.4.2-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```